# SQL performance for string field vs multiple int/varchar fields

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-performance

I'm trying to get the database design right, and I'm uncertain about which of 2 options I should choose. There will be around 20 bool values that are used to filter (4 in the sample for simplicity).

- prop1
- prop2
- prop3
- prop4

**Option 1)**

A int(1) or varchar(1) field for each prop. The filter part of the query could be like

```
WHERE prop1=1 AND prop3=1 AND prop4=1
```

**Option 2)**

Using a single text field with characters representing the props

- a: prop1
- b: prop2
- c: prop3
- d: prop4

Then the filter part of the query similar to option 1 would be like

```
WHERE props LIKE '%a%' AND props LIKE '%c%' AND props LIKE '%d%'
```

or if the characters are sorted:

```
WHERE props LIKE '%a%' AND props LIKE '%cd%'
```

My thought is that option 2 makes it easier to add new props so I like this option, but will the LIKE comparator perform worse than the equality comparator? Does it make any difference to use a single text compared to multiple int(1) or varchar(1)? Any other benefits or drawback that I haven't thought of?

Comment: The string field will be slower for sure. On modern MySQL versions you can use A JSON field that probably will perform better then string field, but still slower then the individual fields probably.

Comment: Stop thinking about performance.

Comment: If the rows you need to filter is only going to be a few hundred - a few thousand then don't worry too much, choose the easiest to work with; if you need this to scale and will be querying millions of rows, being efficient with storage and using integer or small integer values will pay off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary question is whether you can run faster than scanning the entire table.  The answer is "no" unless a small number of the booleans can be handled separately with Index(es).

Your `WHERE bools LIKE '%a%c%d%'` is a clever trick for ANDing any number of flags together.  However, it will need to look at every row, and `LIKE` is slightly heavyweight.

`INT(1)` takes 4 bytes plus overhead.  `TINYINT` is what you are fishing for; it takes 1 byte, plus overhead.

A `SET` with up to 64 bools is another technique.  The coding is a bit clumsy, but it is rather efficient

`INT UNSIGNED` (for up to 32) or `BIGINT UNSIGNED` (for up to 64) flags is implemented similarly to `SET` and also takes up to 8 bytes.  But the coding is rather clumsy.  Let's number the bits starting with 0 in the least significant bit.

```
WHERE (bools & ( (1 << 0) | (1 << 2) | (1 << 3) ) ) = 
               ( (1 << 0) | (1 << 2) | (1 << 3) )
```

would check that bits 0, 2, and 3 are all set.  (This is like your test for a,c,d.)  A variety of ANDs and ORs are possible with this approach.  (You could pre-compute those bit values-- 13 in this example.  Or use a bit literal: `0b1101`.)

The benefit of SET or bits in an INT is the 'speed' within each row.  Still, all rows must be tested.

So, I recommend triaging your bools, etc, and decide what needs indexing and what can go into this combined column or in a combined JSON column for non-bools.

Comment: Thank you, the SET is exactly what I need in my usecase, but I didn't even know it existed!

Comment: @KMK - Also read about its friend `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Answer (score 0):

From performance's point of view both options have drawbacks:

1. It is almost impossible to have proper indexing for 20 columns, regardless of their data types, because queries can vary from setting condition prop1, prop1 + prop2, prop2 + prop3, prop2 + prop4 etc. So you would need a lot of composite indexes. In addition, indexes on boolean values usually don't perform well because of low cardinality (value can be 0 or 1 only, see [here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524651/is-there-any-performance-gain-in-indexing-a-boolean-field)).
2. On the other hand side, LIKE statements with leading % are also a performance issue. Closing % can work, but leading % is determined to be slow.

What I see here that you want to assign a set of attributes to your records, each record can have 0..n assigned `propX`, and you want to filter that efficiently. Like a user can have 0,1,2,...n roles assigned. In relational databases it classifies as a classical many-to-many relationship. If you set up a table with the possible `props` and connect those to your records with a join table, like [detailed here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151904/mapping-many-to-many-relationship) for example, you can make good queries with only a limited number of indexes.